# How can i get more data of my selected option?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one select and i have to get the id and the tipo of my selected option.

My select:

```
<select (change)="setTipoProduto(tipoDoProduto)" [(ngModel)]="tipoDoProduto" name="tipoDoProdutoName"
    class="select-text">
    <option class="dropdown-item" selected>{{tipoDoProduto == null ? 'Tipo do Produto' : tipoDoProduto}}</option>

    <option [hidden]="tipoprodutos[k].tipo == tipoDoProduto" *ngFor="let tipoProduto of tipoprodutos;let k = index"
    class="dropdown-item">{{tipoprodutos[k].tipo}}</option>
</select>
```

How can I pass to my function setTipoproduto the id and tipo that is selected?

My Tipoproduto object have tipoProduto.id and tipoProduto.name, but myngModel only picks the tipo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Put the `ngValue` for the `option`.
>   Modified code as -

```
<select (change)="setTipoProduto(tipoDoProduto)" [(ngModel)]="tipoDoProduto" name="tipoDoProdutoName"
    class="select-text">
    <option class="dropdown-item"  selected>{{tipoDoProduto == null ? 'Tipo do Produto' : tipoDoProduto}}</option>

    <option [hidden]="tipoprodutos[k].tipo == tipoDoProduto" *ngFor="let tipoProduto of tipoprodutos;let k = index"
    class="dropdown-item" [ngValue]="tipoProduto">{{tipoprodutos[k].tipo}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: the [ngValue] must be the same name of my ngmodel?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The selected `option` value will be `ngModel` value and I guess  you are looking for entire object.